Responsive Image Grid
image of my site showing the issue I am having trouble with my Responsive image grid. I got the idea from this website https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp. I want my layout to pretty much be the exact same as this however I am getting vertical whitespace on my medium and large viewports. My columns are not stacking like how it shows on the website

        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/bill-ironstand-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/bill-ironstand-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/bill-ironstand.webp" alt="Portrait of Bill Ironstand">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/christmas-day-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/christmas-day-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/christmas-day.webp" alt="Portrait of a baby on christmas day">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/business-woman-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/business-woman-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/business-woman.webp" alt="Portrait of a business woman">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-3-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-3-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-3.webp" alt="Family Portrait of the Richardsons">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/yellow-mits-front-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/yellow-mits-front-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/yellow-mits-front.webp" alt="Portrait of man with yellow mits">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/sydney-boyce-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/sydney-boyce-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/sydney-boyce.webp" alt="Portrait of Syney Boyce">
                </picture>

            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/adrielle-aquino-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/adrielle-aquino-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/adrielle-aquino.webp" alt="Portrait of Adrielle Aquino">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/alexa-broen-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/alexa-broen-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/alexa-broen.webp" alt="Portrait of Alexa Broen">
                </picture>

                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/band-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/band-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/band.webp" alt="Portait of a Band">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/amie-doucette-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/amie-doucette-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/amie-doucette.webp" alt="Portait of Amie Doucette">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/andrea-klapstein-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/andrea-klapstein-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/andrea-klapstein.webp" alt="Portait of Andrea Klapstein">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/family-portait-2-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/family-portait-2-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/family-portait-2.webp" alt="Second Family Portrait">
                </picture>

            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/blazer-woman-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/blazer-woman-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/blazer-woman.webp" alt="Portait of a woman with a blazer">
                </picture>
               <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/couple-pink-front-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/couple-pink-front-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/couple-pink-front.webp" alt="Portait of a couple">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/blue-suit-2-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/blue-suit-2-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/blue-suit-2.webp" alt="Portait of man in blue suit">
                </picture>

                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/christmas-fam-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/christmas-fam-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/christmas-fam.webp" alt="Portait of a family on christmas day">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/couple-hug-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/couple-hug-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/couple-hug.webp" alt="Portait of a couple embracing">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/blue-suit-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/blue-suit-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/blue-suit.webp" alt="Close up portait of man in blue suit">
                </picture>


            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/curly-hair-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/curly-hair-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/curly-hair.webp" alt="Portait of a woman with curly hair">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/dree-beaudry-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/dree-beaudry-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/dree-beaudry.webp" alt="Portait of Dree Beaudry">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/family-portait-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/family-portait-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/family-portait.webp" alt="Third Family Portrait">
                </picture>

                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/driver-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/driver-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/driver.webp" alt="Portrait of a Driver">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/evan-oliver-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/evan-oliver-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/evan-oliver.webp" alt="Portrait of Evan Oliver">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/yellow-mits-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/yellow-mits-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/yellow-mits.webp" alt="Portrait of a man with yellow mits">
                </picture>

            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/henry-deng-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/henry-deng-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/henry-deng.webp" alt="Portrait of Henry Deng">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/hilary-meng-2-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/hilary-meng-2-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/hilary-meng-2.webp" alt="Portrait of Hilary Meng">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/hilary-meng-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/hilary-meng-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/hilary-meng.webp" alt="Second portrait of Hilary Meng">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/joel-rf-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/joel-rf-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/joel-rf.webp" alt="Portrait of Joel">
                </picture>

                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/man-dog-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/man-dog-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/man-dog.webp" alt="Portrait of a man and his dog">
                </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/man-green-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/man-green-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/man-green.webp" alt="portrait of a man in a green sweatshirt">
                </picture>

                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-bumper-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-bumper-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/nakai-bumper.webp" alt="Portrait of Nakai">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/man-zip-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/man-zip-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/man-zip.webp" alt="Portrait of a man in a zip up jacket">
                </picture>

                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-2-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-2-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/nakai-2.webp" alt="Portrait of Nakai">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/mayra-chavez-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/mayra-chavez-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/mayra-chavez.webp" alt="Portrait of Mayra Chavez">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-close-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-close-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/nakai-close.webp" alt="Portrait of Nakai">
                </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-light-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-light-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/nakai-light.webp" alt="Portrait of Nakai">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-mask-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-mask-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/nakai-mask.webp" alt="Portrait of Nakai">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/nakai-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/nakai.webp" alt="Portrait of Nakai">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-2-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-2-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-2.webp" alt="richardson family portrait">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/richardson-family-photo.webp" alt="richardson family portrait">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/senuda-sydney-2-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/senuda-sydney-2-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/senuda-sydney-2.webp" alt="portrait of Sydney Senuda">
                </picture>


            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/senuda-sydney-md.webp alt=">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/senuda-sydney-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/senuda-sydney.webp" alt="portrait of Sydney and Senuda">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/senuda-wettasinghe-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/senuda-wettasinghe-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/senuda-wettasinghe.webp" alt="portrait of Sydney and Senuda">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/singer-2-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/singer-2-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/singer-2.webp" alt="portrait of a singer">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/singer-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/singer-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/singer.webp" alt="portrait of a singer">
                </picture>
                <picture>
                    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="img-portrait/lisa-bains-md.webp">
                    <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img-portrait/lisa-bains-xs.webp">
                    <img src="img-portrait/lisa-bains.webp" alt="Portrait of Lisa Bains">
                </picture>
            </div>

        </div>

this is my HTML structure above
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0; /* No extra padding */
    margin: 0;  /* No extra margin */
    align-items: flex-start; /* Align items at the top */
  }
  
  .column {
    flex: 1 1 25%; /* Adjust width of columns */
    padding: 0 4px; /* Padding between columns */
    display: flex; /* Make columns flex containers */
    flex-direction: column; /* Stack children vertically */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Ensure padding and border are included in width */
  }
  
  .column img {
    margin: 0; /* Remove margin around images */
    width: 100%; /* Ensure images fit the column width */
    height: auto; /* Ensure images scale correctly */
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .column {
      flex: 1 1 50%; /* Adjust columns to 50% width on medium screens */
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
      flex: 1 1 100%; /* Adjust columns to 100% width on small screens */
    }
  }

Here is my CSS. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong if anybody could help me out that would be greatly appreciated.

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Pls provide a minimal reproducible example. You can use this site https://picsum.photos to add images url with desired size

Your HTML has 8 columns. The css gives each column 25% width.
flex: 1 1 25%; /* Adjust width of columns */
You may have accidentally double-pasted the html, but if that's not the case, you might try setting column widths to 12.5%. As for the spaces, the columns are stacking in 2 rows of 4, despite all of them being in the same "row" div. Your columns also need to end up with similar heights. The W3 schools example shows one column with 6 images, and another has 7. Hope this helps. Always good to see some responsive design too in the html

yea ive tried to play around with the suggestions you provided, i still seem to be having the problem of vertical space only in that one column. it seems like my columns are creating whitespace for more images instead of just everything sitting flush. However thank you for your help i will continue to try and mess around with it. Yea learned a lot about responsive design in school this is just my first time working with so many images in a layout like this!
